# Codeigniter global error override

Tags: codeigniter, error-handling

Is there a way in Codeigniter to override global errors. For instance if an DB error or PHP critical occurs it wont show the error itself but something like 'Our admin guy is fixing the issue' and the error is just logged and emailed.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter lets you handle error messages your way, depending on the HTTP status.
Refer to [this documentation on error handling](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Pos5e5s3dFr3ak's answer, you should handle as many errors as you can manually. For example, if you have a database error, your code should acknowledge (or 'catch') it and perhaps load the appropriate view, or pass it onto a library that will log an email the fault, instead of displaying the intended result.

This method can be used as an alternative, or as an addition to the original answer - sometimes you need not locate the error just by its HTTP response Status Code.

As an example, you may find that the database engine in use is down. If this is the case (you would have to determine if it is indeed down - ie. you are not getting the desired response), you would pass the user on to `example.com/error/database`, for example.